# How to configure the rate filter in snort for windows environment?

Tags: snort

I have installed and configured the snort software for windows environment. As per their documentation, the threshold is deprecated and I have to use other filters. I need to use `rate_filter` in my application, however, I don't know how to set it inside my snort software.

I have read all the documentation and internet resources, and I have added the example codes of `rate_filter` directly to my `snort.conf` file, but still I can't get what I want.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to share your filter to best help here. An example of layout here:

```
Example 1 - allow a maximum of 100 connection attempts per second from any one IP address, and block further connection attempts from that IP address for 10 seconds:

    rate_filter \
        gen_id 135, sig_id 1, \
        track by_src, \
        count 100, seconds 1, \
        new_action drop, timeout 10
```